# How to use media-imdb.com images on a website?

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on a website. It is basically a movie database working with the help of IMDB. I I use images from their server, on localhost I'm able to display them. However, when I put the site on a live server, images are not shown.

I put a single image on different file for testing with this code:

```
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM3OTUyNTI3MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODcyMzM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" style="width:100%;height:300px">
```

See [this demo](http://movieskart.in/aa.html).

However, I am not able to view this image. With firebug, it *does* display image on debug window.

I replaced this image with another image, and I can see that image normally. So: why is the previous IMDB image not shown?

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using AdBlock Plus?

Comment: "With the help of IMDB"? Do they help you voluntarily or is that just a way of saying "I leech content from IMDB"?

Comment: I am able to see the image in your website. Also, I wouldn't recommend stealing image data from IMDB. As far as I'm aware, they do not provide a public API for such things.

Comment: Check the network tab, the image causes a 403. I think you should read the terms of IMDB ;)

Comment: ok, I understand that leeching from IMDB is not a good thing. Ill change the process.  But why is works on localhost?

Answer (score 2):

You get a [403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) response for the image, this means IMDB says it's forbidden to use images like that. You should probably check their [Terms](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions). I'm not a lawyer though, consult one if you think you need one.

The reason you don't get one locally can only be speculated to: it's going to be due to the logic they have in place for determining whether you can grab the image or not. My *guess* would be that their logic can't reliably distinguish your site running locally and just a regular browser request for the image (e.g. when you're browsing imdb.com).

Comment: They could also allow localhost for the benefit of their own developers.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: IMDb does not allow image hotlinking.

When you request the file from the server end, it detects it and blocks your request.

[image]