# 403 (Forbidden) on Images with Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, http-status-code-403

I am running a small application: [here](http://52.39.232.71:8081/movie?query=jurassic) (it might take a while to load the page)

If I run it in my laptop, it shows all images. However, when I deploy it to my server, sometimes the images are shown, sometimes are not with error: 403 (Forbidden)

What is the reason?

Comment: What are your using? example of code? You have to set the good right and group to your images. Your URL contains specific char, you have to encode them with the good html path!

Comment: Does media-imdb.com allow hotlinking?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595262/how-to-use-media-imdb-com-images-on-a-website

Comment: Have you seen this answer. This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151272/given-an-imdb-movie-id-how-do-i-programmatically-get-its-poster-image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot:

Simple answer: IMDb does not allow image hotlinking.

When you request the file from the server end, it detects it and blocks your request.

From:

[How to use media-imdb.com images on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595262/how-to-use-media-imdb-com-images-on-a-website)